# debian 7 - atheros 10a1 ethernet card wireless doesn't work

Tags: wireless-networking, debian-wheezy

i have bought a ideapad z710 a few days ago. I installed debian via using USB stick. During installation, setup cant find my ethernet card. After that i manually install wheezy backports. This solved wired connection but wireless connections still doesnt work.

My win8.1 says that my ethernet driver is :

```
Qualcomm Atheros AR8171/8175 PCI-e
```

Lspci output:

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 08b2 (rev 73)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. Device 10a1 (rev 10)
```

uname -r:

```
3.14-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:25:64:3c:33:73  
      inet addr:192.168.2.75  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::2225:64ff:fe3c:3373/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:3286 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:3699 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:2032455 (1.9 MiB)  TX bytes:573794 (560.3 KiB)
      Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1440 (1.4 KiB)  TX bytes:1440 (1.4 KiB)
```